# @viewchildren vs jquery .What is difference between?

Tags: jquery, angular

Angular has the ability to use viewChildren to hook up to an html element. What is the difference between using this and jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that jQuery objects are unaware of the angular bound events and structures, and that will save you (or give you) a lot of trouble.

if you choose to use JQuery you would have to monkey-patch a lot of the event handling and the data synchronization between JQuery objects and Angular objects.

in short, using viewchildren is far less work.

So if you are choosing to use angular components my advice is to try to minimize the use of JQuery and to use viewchildren when you are faced with a questions between using it and JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit unspecific.

There are quite a few differences. The most obvious would be that `@ViewChildren` or `@ViewChild` is build into angular and doesn't need another library to work. Additionally, `@ViewChild` does not give you a native element directly, but a wrapper containing the element. This is important if you want to use Server Side Rendering (SSR), as you won't have access to the DOM on server side and `@ViewChild` abstracts that for you. If you query an Angular Component, you will get the created instance - this is very helpful, as you will have direct access to the public API of the component.

Another difference is that `@ViewChild` will only allow queries to the `template` that belongs to the `@Component` it is used in, whereas using JQuery would query your whole page.

There are a few more differences, but I guess these would be the most noteworthy ones. Obviously preferred is the usage of `@ViewChild`. Using JQuery in an Angular application is considered a very bad practice.